# How to make html request without full page reload and without ajax

Tags: performance, apache, http, facebook

I saw that facebook is doing that. if you look in the chrome inspector they keep on adding "html documents elements" when you navigate on diferent pages.

I also noticed that google dose this also.

My intention is to make my PHP+DOM load faster under 200 ms from website backed.

It's some web server thing?

I'm using php with apache.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it's "without Ajax" (leaving open the definition of Ajax)?

Comment: If they are 'adding html documents elements' without loading the page, then they are doing DOM manipulation with JavaScript, contacting the server, which, as chryss implies, is Ajax.

Comment: I looked for xhr requests when i navigate through pages and sometimes no xhr was call. 

Basically they are changing the url without reloading the page and then load page elements.

I found also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses BigPipe.

http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Facebook or Google do what you want, but some options here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Answer (score 0):

It's limited in browser support, but WebSockets are technically not Ajax and designed to be very fast because it doesn't have the whole HTTP header overhead.

But there are other ways to improve site-loading performance before resorting to something like this. Look at Google Page Speed, Yahoo's ySlow and other tools to find what bottlenecks exist.