# Is there a way to AJAX load a page and change URL in URL bar without hashing?

Tags: ajax, url

This is probably going to get a resounding no, but I am wondering if it possible to have the URl change dynamically with using hashing, and without invoking a http request from the browser?

My client is keen on using AJAX for main navigation. This is fine, when the end user goes to the front page first, but when they want to use the deep linking, despite it working, it forces an extra load time as the page loads the front page, then invokes the AJAX from the hash.

UPDATE: Could it be possible, given that what I want to avoid is the page reload (the reason is that it looks bad) to stem the reload by catching the hash with PHP before the headers are sent, and redirecting before the page load. This way only one page loads, and the redirect is all but invisible to the user. Not sure how to do this, but seems like it is possible?

Comment: Fuz: You said, "What I propose is not to remove the hash, but when the hash link is used (directly placed in the address bar, or linked from elsewhere) use PHP to redirect to the non-hased url (take the hash out of the above link to see what I mean)z" Why would you need to use a non-hashed URL?

Comment: My thought process has evolved since then, but that remains. I don't want to use hashing because of the latency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...I'm currently working on this problem, but I am unable find a solution that doesn't use a hash in the url (like the example you gave: southasianlitfest.com/#partners), did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: In case someone's still looking for this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that opening an AJAX link of the form `http://example.com/#xyz` results in a full page being downloaded to the browser, and then the AJAX-altered content is changed once the page has loaded and checked the hash part of its URL. The user has a diconcerting experience.

You can hugely improve this by making a page that just contains the static elements - menus, etc. - and a loading GIF in the content area. This page checks its URL upon loading and dynamically fetches the content specified by the hash part. The page can have any URL you want; we'll use `http://example.com/a`. Links to this page (`http://example.com/a#xyz`) now provide a good user experience for users with scripting enabled.

However, new users won't come to the site by fetching `http://example.com/a`; they'll fetch `http://example.com`. This is fine - serve the full page, including the home page content and links that don't require scripting to work (e.g., `http://example.com/xyz`). A script run on loading this page should alter the href of AJAXable links to their AJAX form (`http://example.com/a#xyz`); thus the first link a user clicks on will result in a full page load but subsequent ones won't.

The only remaining problem is is a no-script user gets sent an AJAX link. You can add a `noscript` block to the AJAX page that contains a message explaining the problem and provides a link back to the homepage; you could include instructions on how to enable scripting or even how to modify the link by removing `a#` and pressing enter.

Comment: Not sure if I am following you here, could you explain further?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - I've rewritten the post for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  I often do this to store state in the hash part of the URL.  The result is that the page doesn't reload, but if the user *does* reload, they're taken to the right page.

Using this method, the URL will look like:  "/index#page=home"  or "/index#page=about"

You'll need to write a JavaScript function that handles navigation, and you'll need a containing div that gets rewritten with the contents fetched from AJAX.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="link('home')">Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="link('about')">About</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="link('questions')">Questions</a>
<div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function link(page) {
      location.hash = "page="+page;
      loadPage(page);
   }

   // NOTE: This is using MooTools.  Use the AJAX method in whatever
   // JavaScript framework you're using.
   function loadPage(page) {
       new Request.HTML({
           url: "/ajax/"+page+".html",
           onSuccess: function(tree, elements, html) {
               document.id('content').setProperty('html', html);
           }
       }).get();
    }
</script>
```

Now, you'll also need to have something that checks the hash on page load to load the right content initially.  Again, this is using MooTools, but use whatever onLoad method your JavaScript framework provides.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEvent('domready', function() {
        parts = location.hash.split('=');
        loadPage(parts[1]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In the question I have stated that I don't want the URL to hash, I want to include the actual URL.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without using the hash.  I also don't think that you could cancel the request via PHP before the headers are sent, because in this case the browser would likely interpret it as the user staying on the same page (thus, not rewriting the URL).

I don't understand why the hash method wouldn't work.  Could you provide a more detailed example?

Comment: see how the page loads, and then makes the AJAX call?

Comment: What I propose is not to remove the hash, but when the hash link is used (directly placed in the address bar, or linked from elsewhere) use PHP to redirect to the non-hased url (take the hash out of the above link to see what I mean)

Comment: The browser doesn't send the hash to the server, so there is no opportunity to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great answer, but you can offer a different link in the page itself; e.g., if the address bar shows `/#xyz` you include a link to `/xyz` somewhere in the page. You could also add a link or button that uses script to bookmark the page, which would again use the non-AJAX form of the link.