# Chrome and Firefox doesnot show anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, css

[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884498/anchor-tag-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome)

I also had the same case.

when an image and anchor tags are nested within div tag, the anchor tag doesnot show up when mouse is hoverd on it in firefox and chrome, but works in IE.

I have many div tags in my .cshtml page. Some of the anchor tags in div worked in FF and Chrome

My Application is an MVC3 Application.

here is my code:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="CssDivs">
    <a href="#">
    <img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/home.gif")" alt="home" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The css is :

```
.CssDivs
{
float: left;
padding: 5px;
}
.mainDiv
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    padding: 200px 13px 7px 13px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If any one has solution, please post it.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bzzt6/
this fiddle is working, but it is not working when execute through Visual Studio 2010. what might be the problem?

**Edit:** I've tried `position: relative;` in my css, but it does not make any difference.

Thanks,

Comment: where did you define the anchor tag? it is not showing in the code

Comment: <a href="#">
    <img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/home.gif")" alt="home" border="0" /></a>  i can see it. It is inside <div class="CssDivs">

Comment: float: left and position: absolute together?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRwEL/3/

Comment: karaxuna: yes they are together. some of the div tags working and some are not working

Comment: Blender: yes, it works. Even it is working in IE, but not in FF, Chrome and Safari

Comment: @vijay But it is not showing when i run from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor Tag does not contains href, it has attribute name

check this http://jsfiddle.net/psQvg/

It is working fine for both Chrome and FF

Try check if your javascript is enable or not

Comment: javascript is enabled for all of my browsers