# Why link working perfectly in Internet explorer but not in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am working in a application in which there is a anchor tag with href value = id value of another anchor link. When I click on the anchor tag in Internet explorer its working fine for me but in case of google chrome link is not working. What can be the issue, why working in one browser but not in other

```
1. <ul><li><a href="#Abu Dhabi">Abu Dhabi</a><li> <ul>

2. <a name="#Abu Dhabi" id="&quot;Abu Dhabi&quot;">
<name>Abu Dhabi<br></name></a>
<name>Abu Dhabi<br></name>
```

Comment: What are the two items in the code block meant to be?

Comment: Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884498/anchor-tag-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: I have just menthod the view source of both the items

Comment: Can an id contain a space? I would doubt it.

Comment: can you please provide more detail on this in your question so comment section wont go so long?

Comment: Actually what i shared is the view source of asp.net application

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: `id`s are related to, but not the same as, hash fragments.

Comment: It my case link is working fine in internet exporer but not in google chrome and so want to check the reaons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash fragments cannot contain spaces; yours does. This is covered by [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) in §2.4.3 and §4.