# Wordpress Page Anchor Menu is not working

Tags: html, wordpress

I have used basic HTML anchoring method to move to a particular section of the page.
My website is:
    http://mobihealer.com

I have used the zerif lite theme for my wordpress site. I have a menu "contact us" to move to the "Get in touch" section of the page.

URI of the "contact us" page is:
    http://mobihealer.com/#hello

"hello" is the id attribute of a link which I have inserted just beside the "Get in Touch" heading. This is the target link id. But this method does not work when I am on the landing page which is the default home page. But clicking on "contact us" works when I am on some other page.

I observed that this works on Google Chrome but fails on Firefox.

Comment: Works for me. I'm on Chrome.

Comment: @Aibrean. This is not working on firefox.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884498/anchor-tag-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!