# Customs URL / Deeplinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deep-linking

I have a question.

I have a regular site that i want custom urls to point to these pages when user come to the site.

index.html
-       custom_index.cfm?custom_id=1&page_id=1&inc=index

about.html
-       custom_index.cfm?custom_id=5&page_id=5&inc=about

contactus.html
-       custom_contactus.cfm?custom_id=3&page_id=3&inc=contactus

How can i approach that?

Will something like this work?

```
  if (window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)custom_index.cfm?custom_id=3&page_id=3&inc=contactus($|&)/)) {
Load page
}
```

Comment: Wait, wait, Cold Fusion?  Maybe it is beyond your control to have to use it... but you might want to check out this article: http://aralbalkan.com/1864

Answer (score 0):

Apache `mod_rewrite` should help you here - check out [this article](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) that should get you on your way.

Good luck!

Comment: What's the point? What happens when a website visitor returns to blah.com/about.html and the page doesn't exist so they get a 404 error? You will need to use mod_rewrite to redirect all of your 404 errors to a specific page to handle this when you may as well just write code once rather than thrice - once for your URL rewrite handler in JS, once for your 404 handler to translate and finally your mod_rewrite 404 handler

Comment: With 20 seconds of searching I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page) that should give you the answer you're looking for