# Window Location getParameter is always null in GWT/GXT Project?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

I am working GWT/GXT
I am trying to practise some sample Examples.

This is url of the project

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/Opera_Star.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

public void onModuleLoad() {
        Map<String, Entry> project = new FastMap<Entry>();
        ProjectModel projectModel = new ProjectModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < projectModel.getChildren().size(); i++) {// 1 children
            LoginCategory loginCategory = (LoginCategory) projectModel
                    .getChildren().get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < loginCategory.getChildren().size(); j++) {// 2 children
                Entry entry = (Entry) loginCategory.getChildren().get(j);
                project.put(entry.getId(), entry);
            }
        }   
        Registry.register(MODEL, projectModel);
        String id = Window.Location.getParameter("id");
        if (id == null) {
            id = XDOM.getBody().getId();
        }    
        Entry entry = project.get(id);    
        if (entry == null) {
            return;
        }
```

Can Anybody tell me What is `String id = Window.Location.getParameter("id");`, How to `setParameter` for `Windows.Location`

What is `id = XDOM.getBody().getId();`

I am getting Id null.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your `EntryPoint` class

```
private static Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    Map<String, List<String>> paramsMap = Window.Location.getParameterMap();
    for (String key : paramsMap.keySet()) {
        List<String> values = paramsMap.get(key);
        if (values.size() > 0) {
            String value = values.get(0);
            queryParams.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
            queryParams.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> I dont have &id=foo in the url, how to add it in the URL?

- [Change URL in browser address bar without reload existing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953792/change-url-in-browser-address-bar-without-reload-existing-page)
- [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

---

How to get the host page base URL?

```
GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(); //http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

Answer (score 0):

`Window.Location.getParameter` parses the URL's query-string into name-value pairs.

So `Window.Location.getParameter("id")` would return `foo` if the URL had `id=3` in the query-string (e.g. `?id=foo` or `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&id=foo`)

I don't know what `XDOM` is, but I guess `XDOM.getBody().getId()` is no different form `Document.get().getBody().getId()`, so it would return the value of an `id` attribute on the `<body>` element (e.g. `<body id=foo>`)

Comment: I dont have `&id=foo`  in the url, how to add it in the URL?
when i run the Application i get this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Opera_Star.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`