# URL replace .php?id=1 extension for a <h3> tag value from my content

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Pretty hard question.

I've got some pages with an url extension of .php?id=1, .php?id=2, .php?id=34, etc.

Now I have got on all of these pages, a `<h3>` containing some text.
This text I would like to have in place of the .php?id=4(i.e.) extensions.

I would like to know how I might be able to achieve this. Any help is welcome! :)

[image]

the red has to be replaced with the green, separated by a slash.

**My .htaccess code so far:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projecten-functioneel.php?args=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `if ($some_condition) { do_something(); }` What the condition/something are is up to you

Comment: Could you give some visual example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: @AlejandroArbiza I've made an update ;)

Comment: I'd imagine you're looking for seo friendly urls.

Something like 
somesite.com/Inventory/detail/22340

You can setup apache to do a 
[mod_rewrite][1].


Then install a skeleton framework like [panique][2] to handle the routing.


  [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
  [2]: https://github.com/panique/php-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at this configuration

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^projecten-functioneel/(.*)$ projecten-functioneel.php?title=$1 [L]
```

The first four lines are your original settings with the only addition being the flag **L** at the end of the rewrite rule. This will prevent the second rewrite rule to be evaluated if the first one matches.

The last line is the one that takes care of the projecten-functioneel page request.

**How it works**

If the URL is

```
site.com/projecten-functioneel/some_title
```

the request will be rewritten to

```
site.com/projecten-functioneel.php?title=some_title
```

Then in your `projecten-functioneel.php` file you have to ask for `$_GET['title']`, which in this case will be `some_title`.

Comment: When I paste the provided code on your thread, changing RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?args=$1 [QSA,L] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projecten-functioneel.php?args=$1 [QSA,L] Nothing really changes...

Comment: What about, if(URL == '?id=1') then (URL -> '/afdekbanden'); I made this code up btw..

Comment: Oh no, that is not where it is supposed to go. By your comment I take that you are not familiar with **.htaccess**; in which case I would suggest extreme caution: **please make back-up copies of every file you modify** so you can put everything back as it was if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the back-up tip. I've made a big mistake by not using a database so I won't either be able to work with any SQL. So, now I'm trying to work around by picking a <h1> title from the page and replace the ?id= with that specific title, as explained in the main question. Guess that just isn't possible anyhow.

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ The first part they talk about, called 'What is URL rewriting', is exactly what I need. They don't explain how to achieve it though

Comment: I found this other question that might be more aligned to what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953792/change-url-in-browser-address-bar-without-reload-existing-page I wonder if that is really what you want though.

Comment: Well, in the answer to the question I linked you to in the answer, I explain how to do it. However, those rules are meant to go in the the site's .htaccess file, not in the URL nor the PHP code. You should know the basics about the .htaccess file before you try to customize it though.

Comment: I know it's hard to help me out.. I've paste your provided code and changed the index.php?id=$1 to my own projecten-functioneel/php?id=1.. That just does not do the job unfortunately. I guess I'll have the url like this forever

Comment: Could you add in your question the .htaccess file please?

Comment: I've made an update containing my .htaccess code. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are likely (at least) two changes that will need to be made to `projecten-functioneel.php`.

1) It will need to change its query for articles to look them up by the keyword that is in the  tag;

For example, you probably have code in there today that looks something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You will need to change this to look something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title=?");
$pathinfo = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$stmt->execute(array($pathinfo[0]));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

2) You will need to change how links are written, so that future links are generated consistent with this behaviour.

Assuming something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM articles");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<a href="/projecten-functioneel.php?id=', $row->id, '">', $row->title, '</a>';
}
```

to something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM articles");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<a href="/projecten-functioneel.php/', $row->title, '">', $row->title, '</a>';
}
```