# Mask URL with website title

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, title, mask

How I can mask with javascript or .htaccess the URL (in the adress bar) with title of website?

In other words:

This is adress bar:

```
-----------------------------------------
http://mysite. com
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to show my title of page

```
---------------------------------------
Page Title
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: It's not possible to do this

Comment: Have you seen this done somewhere?

Comment: Like APAD1 stated, it's impossible to do this. Fortunately you can change the browser tabs title by updating the <title></title> tag inside the <head> of your HTML. For example the title of this page is "javascript - Mask URL with website title - Stack Overflow" which you see in the tab.

Comment: In the Android browser , at least in Mozilla Frefox . I can do this in  browser settings .

Comment: Instead of URL I want to display the page title .

Comment: Or a text that I set.

Comment: Have  you seen that somewhere ? I'm curious to see an example

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox on Android.

Comment: Then that would be the browser's decision. The server cannot make decisions like that. The only title you can set is within the `<title>` tags, and the browser can leverage that as much as it likes.

Comment: Replacing the actual URL with something else sounds like a great tool for a phishing site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the string in the url bar to a random text. The address bar will always contain an url, and that url will always begin with your domain.

If a browser would opt to display a text in the url bar instead of the actual url, it would be the title you set for your page. This happens in the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` of your html document.

You can change the displayed url through the `window.history` api of javascript, but this will only allow you to change the url to one that is relative to your domain. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10953792/2209007) for more information.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/q/214512/203349) will give a general overview of the functionality of mod_rewrite, a module for Apache, that you can use to translate url requests to a specific file on your server. You can also make the browser do a redirect, but you will not get anything sensible out of it when the redirect isn't to an url.