# Change complete URL in adress bar, without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

What I need is for a webpage to completely alter the users adressbar on visit.

For instance: I visit www.X.com, but my adress bar displays www.Z.com.

I have already looked at history.pushState / history.replaceState, but using them I get results like this: www.X.com/www.Z.com.

Is there a way, preferably using history.pushState/replaceState, to accomplish this effect?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953792/change-url-in-browser-address-bar-without-reload-existing-page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I have tried those, but like I said they append to the adress bar instead of replacing it fully.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeUrl(page, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
$(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        changeUrl('Page1', 'Page1.htm');
    });
    $("#button2").click(function () {
        changeUrl('Page2', 'Page2.htm');
    });
    $("#button3").click(function () {
        changeUrl('Page3', 'Page3.htm');
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain what the code does instead of just placing a piece of code.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the issue with my hosting provider.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The actual answer to the question is that it is not possible, for security reasons, to alter the hostname in the browser bar without reloading the page.