# Pretty URL mask for address bar url

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a way to provide a 'pretty URL' mask for the URL in the browser address bar that goes back to its actual value when copied?

Modern browsers do something like this by hiding `https://www.` visually but if you copy the URL it's actually there. I want this behaviour but with text of my choosing covering parts of the url of my choosing.

Comment: Like, with HTML? If so just set `href` to the actual link then put the text as the "pretty url"

Comment: @S.C. No. In the actual address bar.

Comment: Then no, you can't detect copying of the URL in the address bar, not even sure you could change the URL without it redirecting away.

Comment: You can change it without redirecting, e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953792/change-url-in-browser-address-bar-without-reload-existing-page. But this isn't quite the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't really see why it shouldn't be possible as long as the address is still relative to your domain.