# Jquery scroll to, add #

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need help, I'm building a one page layout webpage and I have a scroll to script but I want when I press the button in the nav bar class to appear. What I mean?

When ever I press a button it scrolls to the position but I want to see htttp://mysite.com/#top

This is what I have

```
    $(function(){
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if ($target.length) {
            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset - 100}, 800); /* Offest 100px because of the fixed nav manu */
            return false;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So - to restate your question for clarification... you currently have a system working where pushing a button will cause you to jump to the correct place on the page.  You would like it to also change the displayed URL to reflect the jump.  Is this correct?

Comment: If that is, indeed, what you need, then apparently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page has the answer for you (though I admit it took me a while of reading to understand fully).

Comment: That is it but where do I put it, total JS noob here. Sorry

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I not fully understand the question, but if you want the hash (#top) to be displayed, you should just delete `return false;` from your code.