# add parameter to parent url

Tags: jquery

I have a  page where I need to add parameter to this url when particular tipster is clicked on.

This is what I have:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Tipster").hide();

```
var qs = jQuery.parseQuerystring();

if (qs['tipster']) {
    currentTipster = parseInt(qs['tipster']);
    ShowTipster(currentTipster);


    if (qs['tipstertip']) {
        ShowTipsterTip(parseInt(qs['tipstertip']));
    }
}

if (qs['tipsterbio']) {
    currentTipster = parseInt(qs['tipsterbio']);
    ShowTipster(currentTipster); ShowTipsterBio();
}



$("#TipstersHomeContainer").css("display", "");
$("#TipsterContainer").css("display", "");
```

});

```
jQuery.extend({
  parseQuerystring: function(){
    var nvpair = {};
    var qs = window.location.search.replace('?', '');
    pairs = qs.split('&');
    $.each(pairs, function(i, v){
      var pair = v.split('=');
      nvpair[pair[0]] = pair[1];

});
return nvpair;
```

}
});

Comment: I assume the parameters are generated from the parseQueryString function. One thing I can't figure out is the URL where the parameters should go to. Which one is it?

Comment: the url shoud be something like window.location.href + '?tipster'

Comment: Wouldn't it be as easy as doing a `window.location.href + '?tipster=' + currentTipster`?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure where to place it inside function

Comment: Ummm... Anywhere you want to do a redirect for your page? The decision is all up to you. Just give it a try and you'll find out the right place.

Comment: it's actually not riderect, i can not reload page, just add id to url.

Comment: I difine variable var tipurl= "";
and give it a value:var tipurl = window.location.href + '?tipster=' + currentTipster;

Comment: I assume problem solved?

Comment: No, variable is not showing in url

Comment: Butt if I add it mannualy it's loading right content on the page: http://myurl/Tipsters/Tipster_Landing.html?tipster=4

Comment: Right. Maybe you should try looking into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved. I was on the right truck, simple variable misspelling was  the problem