# Remove hash from URL window.location.hash

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, hash, window.location

I need to remove the # from my URL so that the completed URL is example.com/sub-page-title instead of example.com/#sub-page-title.

I was able to get a repetative URL to go away using substr(31), 31 being the length of the URL including http://... but I'm sure that is not the ideal way to do this.

NOTE: I cannot have a page refresh.

On click, an external page is loaded into a div (which then slides into place)...once that is visible, I want the URL to reflect this (without #). That way going forward and hitting "Back" will bring the users to the actual page.

CODE:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('a.load').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
    });


    $('a.load').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #project-details';
        $('.wide-frame').animate({
            left: -985,
            duration: 'slow'
        })
    $('#project-details article').hide();   
    $('#project-details').fadeIn('normal',loadContent);


    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(31);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#project-details').load(toLoad,showNewContent)
    }
    function showNewContent() { 
        $('#project-details').show('normal');
        $.getScript("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/ajax-control.js");
    }
    return false;

    }); 

});
```

I don't know if this is pertinent, but I am also using Hash history with jQuery BBQ for some other navigation features.

Comment: I believe what you want to do has already been addressed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).

Answer (score 0):

How about a nice little [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) ?

Otherwise just use the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method.

like this :

```
var string = "url/#hash";
string.replace('#','');
```

Comment: Unless you want to expand your answer to be more than a link, and to include code snippets or an example, this should be a comment (at best).

Comment: I don't know how to add comments haha. Shame on me.

Comment: Yes, sorry...I'm real savvy with HTML/CSS PHP...but this other stuff is a little outside my understanding, I pieced together the above, but now I'm stuck!

Comment: I responded before you changed your answer...I tried adding your solution in a couple of places within the code I pasted above, but nothing is happening. Where should I put it??

Comment: What is the URL you want to remove the # from ? Is it $(this).attr('href').substr(31); ? Then do $(this).attr('href').substr(31).replace('#','');

Comment: Adding $(this).attr('href').substr(31).replace('#',''); doesn't remove the hash...?? Here is the dev site if you want to see it [link](http://trademarkvisual.com/dev). Clicking on any of the squares will show you what is happening. The full code (including your solution) is in the footer.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you edit your question or something ?

Comment: I don't know how to rephrase the question...all I want to do is get the # out of the URL. The replace() method isn't doing it.