# Add search filter to URL without using Javascript(C# MVC3)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this url //domain/search-results/

I would like add filters to the URL but without using Javascript everytime the user click a filter, so the url grows like //domain/search-results/filter/filter/...

I can solve this by adding the filter via javascript to the action method, but I want to avoid this solution if possible.

I can't use redirect because it will cause the page to load twice (once for domain/search-results and another one domain/search-results/filter)

Thanks.

Comment: How is it possible to alter the url without a server side operation and a javascript. you have to choose from either of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the url without reloading the page, but you're probably going to have to use javascript. see
[Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page) and [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511) 
good luck

Comment: Finally serialize the object to URL.
Do a "return Reditec(URL)" and centralize all of requests through one action.