# How do I use javascript to make my URL reflect site navigation? And also be linkable?

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

My website uses a single page, which loads all its content in iframes, and I would like to know how I can make the page URL change when each piece of content is viewed. 
Then I would also like these URLs to work as links to the content.

Here is my site:
http://www.dosed.co.uk

If you click any project, you'll see what I mean. I want to be able to link someone to a specific project (so something like "http://www.dosed.co.uk?project=fish").

How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: First of all you should really try not to use iframes and normally the ?project=whatever is when you are using php. I would recommend instead looking into a lightbox or something like that

Comment: You might have a look at the history api. You might also want to make a script that shows a different content, depending on the value of `location.pathname`

Comment: @BradM - sorry I didn't realise this wasn't allowed.

I've managed to get the URL to update on clicking a link, and make it reset when the popup is closed. The only issue now is how to make that link work from other places... Is there maybe a way of translating a list of URLs into javascript actions?