# Difference between clientside and serverside (ajax) rendering for search page, concerning SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, client-side-templating

I'm working on a page that is more or less a search tool, it basically consists of an input field, and it will show a list of entries to the user, according to the input.  In this situation, **if there any difference for SEO if the page uses client or server-side rendering (using AJAX) and why?**

I'm just concerned if it's a disadvantage if I use client-side rendering in this particular scenario.

I understand that client-side rendering is a disadvantage for SEO compared to server-side - when the HTML is complete at the beginning, so to say. But in a dynamic case, where the results have to be loaded asynchronously anyways, is it still a disadvantage? Does it depend if the current content can be mapped to a URL?

Comment: You can do both... but first why don't you let us know the reasons you'd go with either of the methods?

Comment: Because right now I just want to know about the SEO part... There's a lot of information about other aspects, which I'm reading, but I couldn't clear this.

Comment: Any content loaded via ajax/javascript may not be available for an indexing bot.

Comment: Okay, I guess my question was overcomplicated - so in these cases it doesn't make any difference if I'm rendering this content in the server or in the client.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Yes it's about SEO but it's also about programming, if I ask this in a "SEO site" probably nobody can answer because of the programming part. This is a quite narrow way to view the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to be much concerned with UI/UX and want to know more about SEO, I'd suggest to go with the client side. Anything that's dynamically loaded after user's input *won't* be visible to web crawlers.

However, another approach would be to make it work both ways - so that by visiting a specific URL (`site.com/search?q=something`) you get the page fully rendered from the server side, while you're still able to make another search that will happen at the client side. You'd still have a little trouble indexing all the relevant searches, but perhaps you could track the last x searches and show them somewhere on the page, with links to full server-side rendered search pages, like the one I mentioned above. You can even make those dynamic calls not only change the content of the page, but the URL hash in the browser's address bar as well (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)).

That way you'd provide users with a nice user interface/experience, while still doing a very nice SEO job since the crawlers would be able to index the links from the list of last searches.

So, to directly answer your question: client-side vs. server-side page rendering - **huge** SEO difference

Answer (score 3):

`AJAX` loading of content has no impact on `SEO`.

The updating of the DOM via JavaScript will not result in any noticeable changes in what is indexed by a search bot. Almost all legitimate search engines archive the non-dynamic version of a webpage.

In order to enable SEO you have to maintain embedded links to non-dynamic versions of that content.

For example (using jQuery):

```
 <div class="next-page"><a class="ajax-me" href="/page-2.html">Page 2</a></div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax-me").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefaults();
        $('#ajax-target').load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
 });
```

That will enable AJAX for links, but still make that link visible to the web crawler for search engines.

Your server will have to know to respond with either a full webpage or AJAX response based upon the header request.