# Updating address bar with new URL and no hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-history

In my project I am using this Ajax function (below) to get the content (it works really well ^^).

Anyway  I would like to have a nicer looking URL (to be honest I am no fan of the hashtag,) with the script I have been using until now I get something like this: `http://example.com/#sitename`

To change that I did some research: I learnd this: `the window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');` JavaScript line (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page) more information on updating URL without reloading)

I should be able to actually change the url so that I would like it.
now my problem is that I am a total beginner whit programming (And when I tried to include it in to the code it broke and nothing worked anymore.) and wanted to ask if someone could help me include it in the code (below)

Also I heard of the [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) - library if I read correctly this should also should do the trick whit, but like I said I am inexperienced and have to ask how to include it  to the ajax-call (I mean to include it in to my code) or is that not possible?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var e = "", t = $("#content");
        $("ul:not(.no) li a").click(function() {
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        });
        $(window).bind("hashchange", function() {
            e = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            url = e;
            if (e) {
                t.fadeOut(200, function() {
                    url = url.replace("#", "");
                    $("#loading").css("visibility", "visible");
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "load_page.php",
                        data : "page=" + url,
                        success : function(e) {
                            if (parseInt(e) != 0) {
                                t.fadeIn(200, function() {
                                    $("#content").html(e);
                                    var $title = $("#title").text();
                                    document.title = "JuBla | " + $title;
                                });
                            }
                            $("#loading").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        }
                    });
                    $("li a").removeClass("current");
                    $('li a[href="" + e + ""]').addClass("current");
           //my attempted solution                      //    window.history.pushState('/'+ url, $title, '/' + url + '/')
                });
            }
        });
        $(window).trigger("hashchange");
    });
```

Comment: You should include the attempted solution

Comment: @nietonfir it is special for this code

Comment: @Oriol see the Commented part

Comment: @adho12 I don't understand. You say you want to get rid of hashes, and use new history API instead; but you try to use the new API inside a `hashchange` event listener. If you don't want hashes, why are you trying to use `hashchange`?

Comment: @Orion That is my main problem I don't realy get this code so i asked how to rewrite it so that I coud define the URL my self