# Domain "Masking" to show https status

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm looking to permanently "mask" my domain to show its new https status as well as block the subdirectories from showing up in the URL bar. Is this possible?

For example, it's currently mydomain.com and when someone goes inside, it'll show mydomain.com/page1

I'm hoping to make it so that it's permanently https://mydomain.com no matter where they navigate along my site. Is this possible and if so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are referring to is `address bar` manipulation, having control over that from a website would be a security risk, and therefore it is not possible. Some modern browsers will highlight the domain, no matter what URL is being used (latest version of Chrome and FF do this). But it is a feature of the browser, not of the site. So in short, you cannot do what you are asking to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's redirect; add the following line to your virtual host/server config for your HTTP server.

```
Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.com/
```

You will also need to perform the same redirect for each of your sub-domains available via HTTPS.

This will not prevent the user from seeing the path however.

To change the address bar, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).