# Hide #div from URL

Tags: javascript, url, html

Clicking on a link. The #div is a link that takes the person to a certain part of the page . My url is something like this:

> http://link.com.br/#div

and I would like the url was just:

> http://link.com.br

I would like to take this #div  the end of the url. I think javascript would solve my problem, but I'm a * shit * about it

Please, help :( 
Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you can't edit the html?

Comment: That would stop the expected behaviour of the in-page bookmark. Is this what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First approch

... would be to just write the hyperlink as:

```
<a href="http://link.com.br">http://link.com.br</a>
```

#### Second thing,

... using JS!

```
history.pushState('', 'Current Page Name', window.location.replace('/#div', ''))
```

This second method would replace the URL with the new one! You can just use the desired URL in the last parameter!

It can be as:

```
history.pushState('', 'Current Page Name', 'http://link.com.br');
```

Now, this will update the current URL to the one that is provided in the last paramter (third parameter).