# How to implement jQuery Mobile Animated Ajax page navigation (transitions) in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have been using CSS3 based animations to animate the pages using javascript in Single page applications. Recently I worked with jQuery mobile. For all links by default jQuery Mobile loads the pages with ajax and animates them.

**One way I can do is by appending url hash (this is how gmail works). But I dont want to use hashes, I want to change the complete url like the way jQuery Mobile does it.**

Can we implement the same functionality for Single page application using just javascript.

Need the help very badly.

Comment: I believe that's done using `history.pushState()`

Comment: you need to load external pages into DOM via Ajax as jQM does, in order to animate/alternate views.

Comment: @Omar Thanks, Will be grateful if you can provide solution, because I am also struggling with the same problem

Comment: @Venky it is similar to coding a brand new framework. It's not about loading and animating, it involves updating history and creating custom events in order to handle transition between pages/views.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for your help. I will try to implement it bit by bit.

Comment: @Venky you can go through [jQM JS on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js) code to get an idea how jQM does it. Also, you can [download a custom jQM library](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) including widgets/events you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Url, you can use something like this:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

See this link for more information: [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

If you want to load some content into the DOM using AJAX (Which allows you to do your view fading etc) you would do something like this:

```
$('.ajax_content').load( 
    //The Url + Only fetch this div from the page.
    $(this).attr('href') + ' #someDiv', 
    function() {
        //Do something when it's complete.
    }
);
```

`.ajax_content` would be the div you are loading the content into.

Note: `+ ' #someDiv'` is optional. It allows you to only load a certain div in the Url you are loading (so you can avoid loading all the body into your DOM again.

More information about `.load()` can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin

It can load page via ajax and the urls could be customized to whatever you want.