# updating from a # url to a / to improve naming

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to update part of my website to have more friendly URLs.

Currently I am using #tags at the end of the URL which means the page doesn't refresh when say I go from `example.com/trucks` to `example.com/trucks#1234_235_23`

But I want to transfer that to be

```
example.com/tracks/large/standard/VXR-Maloo
```

But this needs to work in IE7 and 8 and also needs to not refresh the page after I go to `example.com/trucks`.

I was thinking of a history API but this will not work for IE7/8 so does anyone have any suggestions?

The back end is on a java platform.

Comment: This needs to be done server-side.  You can do it with rewrite rules (.htaccess or web.config) or with url rewriting in a server-side language.

Comment: how will that work if the page isnt to refresh?

Comment: Actually, I take it all back.  Times they are a changing! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Comment: thanks - bit that is only for modern browsers

Comment: He just said he wants an IE7/8 solution, which isn't compatible with HTML5 history APIs http://caniuse.com/history

Comment: Thanks @Interrobang - he already said that :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible client-side without the history API.

Comment: Sorry it's not what you wanted Dan.  Just force your users to upgrade :p

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method to do this that will work across all browsers.

Consider falling back to a hash-based implementation only on old browsers that don't support History APIs. You can do this with a module such as [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js).