# Remove name token from browser url

Tags: gwt, gwtp, errai

We have a website, where a user can open a layer to make payments.
This layer is implemented with GWTP and Errai as a modal layer, which can be closed (means, we hide that layer). If we hide the layer, we still have the last name token in the URL field, which means, if the user reloads the page, the last place is load by the PlaceManager.

Is there any possibility (either with GWTP or even plain JavaScript) to remove the name token from the URL field, when we hide the layer (the hide action is done with an EventHandler from Errai).

Basically, what i want to achieve is the same functionality as Facebook has, when you open a picture. The picture is then shown in a modal layer, the URL field of the browser changes to the picture url, and when you close the layer, the URL changes back to "facebook.com".

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page