# How to provide different URLs for two clickable elements on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have two clickable elements in HTML like this:

**HTML**

```
var node1 = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item"">' + fileName1 + '</a>');
var node2 = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item"">' + fileName2 + '</a>');
```

They belong to the page with url say:

```
http://foobar/examples.html
```

They have `onclick` listeners attached to them that retrieve some data from the server and display it on the webpage

**Javascript**

```
node1.click(function () {/*Displays table1*/})
node2.click(function () {/*Displays table2*/})
```

I want to change the URL for the two clicks just so that if I open the URL in a fresh tab, I get the `node` element clicked and the data visible. For example, conceptually, the following URL should point to the `node1` clicked and data for it visible:

```
http://foobar/examples.html##fileName1  (does not work, but you get the idea)
```

I do not want to change the URL in accordance with what has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page) as I do not want to create an HTML page for every `fileName` (it is an increasing list). Anchors don't help either as they just open `http://foobar/examples.html` and none of the `nodes` clicked . Neither is the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) very clear to me. Can someone please help?

Comment: I don't see any URLs here.

Comment: The questions you linked are about updating the location dynamically, but what it sounds like you want is to load a URL with one of your two blocks of data already showing. Is that correct?

Comment: I have added more information with URLs now. And yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The first link you gave for changing the URL is what you want. However, you don't change the HTML page - you can add *URL variables*. For example:

http://www.example.com/mypage.html?node1=1&node2=1

Then you need to write a Javascript function at the top of your document to read the URL variables, and display the nodes that are set to 1 (or whatever value you choose) when the document has been loaded. For an example of how to read URL variables, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You could give your nodes identifiers, like:

```
var node1 = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="fileName1">' + fileName1 + '</a>');
var node2 = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="fileName2">' + fileName2 + '</a>');
```

You would need to adjust the file names to be valid IDs.

Add the following JS:

```
var nodeId= window.location.hash;
$(nodeId).click();
```

You could then use:

```
http://foobar/examples.html#fileName1 (where fileName1 is adjusted as for IDs).
```