# URL change when scrolling on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change URL of the site when i scrolling the page. When I scrolling the page,URL of the page will automatically change after each content.

Comment: what have you tried so far share some code. And use `.scroll()` jquery event with `#` values.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

1. Detecting scrolling and entering sections

   You do this by using the `scroll` event on `window`, and then comparing the `scrollTop` to the position of the section(s) you want to compare to.
2. Changing the URL

   You have a few choices here:

   1. You can set the hash fragment (the `#xyz` part of the URL) by assigning to `location.hash`. Doing that will create a history entry, though, so I don't recommend it. (If just scrolling a page added a bunch of entries to my browsing history, I wouldn't be a happy user.)
   2. You can use `location.replace(newUrl)` using the current URL updated with a new hash, which *won't* create a history entry.
   3. You can use `history.pushState` with any (reasonable) URL you want in modern browsers. Again that will create a history entry.
   4. You can use `history.replaceState` with any (reasonable) URL you want in modern browsers, which *won't* create a history entry.

   More about the `history` API [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).