# How to reload current page with variable from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax form to send post data to a php file. And want to reload the current page with variable response from that php. Actually I need to update only the url in address bar after success response. This is my code:

```
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        var data;
        if(data && data != 'error') {
            window.history.pushState("string", "Title", "article.php?do=$_GET[do]&token='+data+'");
        }else{
            $('#saveStts').html('error');
        }
```

My response variable from php is a time stamp like `1433428606`. I need this number to reload a page with the full url is :
`www.test.com/admin/article.php?do=edit&token=1433428606`. I tried but always reload with `data` instead of timestamp from a server. Please be advice.

Comment: If you're reloading and going to a new URL, you don't need ajax, just do a normal post.

Comment: You can call window.location.assign(url) after success response

Comment: Duplicate: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

This state push can be done in Chrome, Safari, FF4+, and IE10+.

The way you're currently doing looks right, are you having any troubles?

window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");

There's a very good response on the topic here: [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: The thing is I can't get the response code from php file to reload the url. The response code is a time stamp `1433418642` and I need this number to reload the page with. The full url is `http://www.test.com/admin/edit.php?id=xxx&token=1433418642`

Comment: Why are you re-initiating/overwriting the variable data? You can remove "var data;". If you still have an issue after removing that line, explode data, like console.log(data) and see what is getting returned.