# How to change the url without refreshing or reloading page on when radio button checked?

Tags: php, wordpress

Question: I want to change the url of page without refreshing but now when i checked on radio button the page refreshes and change the url. for Example,

My current Page url is: www.example.com/cart/

when i checked pickup, day and time radio button then page will refresh 
and shows url:

www.example.com/cart/?method_choice=pickup&time=12PM-3PM&day=tue

but i want page will not refresh and url will change when radio button is checked.

Comment: Please check:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-Browser-URL-without-reloading-refreshing-page-using-HTML5-in-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx,    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting the page to refresh?

```
// Reloads current page
document.location.reload();

// Go to page
window.location = "http://www.example.com/cart/?method_choice=pickup&time=12PM-3PM&day=tue";
```

Comment: You should use comments to ask questions, not answers

Comment: I was a little quick with my answer and noticed that I used the wrong location to ask a question. I then was in the process of creating an answer. No need to vote something down less than a minute after the post without giving the poster the ability to correct their mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can use history.pushState();

For example:

```
history.pushState('', '', '/cart/?method_choice=pickup&time=12PM-3PM&day=tue');
```