# working with htaccess - page not being loaded properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have the following code written in my `.htaccess` document

```
RewriteEngine On


# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^category/([a-z]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

the problem I think occurs in the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1
```

Essentially I want when a user type `searchPage.php?crs_category=business`
it rewrite the url to `category/business` or `category/business/` or `category/BUSinesS/` or `category/BUsineSS`

As it stands the **following problems** with this line is as follow:

1. the css/js seems to load
2. it only works when i type category/business/ if i type searchPage.php?crs_category=business it does not redirect or rewrite to the clean URL

Comment: rewrite rule won't be able to do that for you. use javascript, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage.php\?crs_category=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ category/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$  searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, and suggestion, though two things: on local host the rewrite seems to rewrite it as such http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/category/Web%2520development where at default it was localhost/website/ and i type localhost/website/searchPage.php?category=business  the second issue is for some reason the relvant css/js files are not loaded when url rewrite is done

Comment: Uncomment or add the RewriteBase / line , and to solve js a nd css issue you can 
change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags ,add 

    `<base href="/">`