# How do you hide a filename in the url with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a file called "index.html" that I don't want to convert to a View in my project.  When I browse to this file, I see:

"mydomain.com/index.html"

in the browser's address window, but I would instead just like to see:

"mydomain.com"

How can I accomplish this in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Answer (score 1):

If you are navigating to it you can link to the root of your site "/" or "mydomain.com" instead of "index.html". Example:

Instead of this:

```
<a href="/index.html">Some Page</a>
```

Do this:

```
<a href="mydomain.com">Some Pag</a>
```

Just a suggestion but I would just convert the file to a view so you can take advantage of the framework as well as things like routing to display the url how you want.

Comment: It's important to note that this works only because "index.html" is typically set up as a default page in web servers. However, that's not always the case and can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the url after the page has loaded with javascript:

```
window.history.pushState("yada", "Title", "/mydomain.com");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)