# What unexpected things can I learn about a user from their browser?

Tags: javascript, user-agent, navigator

I'm giving a class of high school students a demo of unexpected things a webpage can tell about them from their mobile - even if they're not signed in or anything. So far I have picked a couple of things most people would know about, like:

Device OS

Specific handset (unless you're on iPhone, then it's just iPhone)

Language setting

And a couple of more obscure things:

Carrier (hitting a remote service and returning JSONP since js is IP naive)

Battery level / charge status (I didn't even know you could do this until today)

Can you think of anything else cool / creepy in a similar vein that I can dig out of UA / Navigator / etc? Most of them are running Chrome under Android or iOS (which is lucky, not every browser supports the battery thing). The main event is about mobile safety and phishing so I'd like to stick to mobile phones.

Quick edit: for clarity, I'm building out a site they will go to which will actually demo these features - so unfortunately they need to be implemented, at least in Chrome, vs planned / drafts.

Comment: orientation/acceleration events can tell you if they have shaky hands or the phone is sitting on a table, or they are using it in bed leaning back. the light sensor is also fun but not very precise.

Comment: Orientation is a nice one! Thanks :)

Comment: Well if they confirm a dialog, you can get their video camera and microphone input using javascript API. Facebook even does no-flash video calls now in modern browsers, presumably using WebSockets.

Comment: That's very interesting - I was mainly looking for non-authorized actions (e.g hey, this is spooky and you didn't explicitly allow it). However - probably out of time for this year's session, but if I run it again I could write a little "how fast can you tap" game that uses knowledge of the device to put a tap target immediately under the "confirm" button and delay the dialogue until the user reached a certain speed. Although I suspect Android and iOS are smart enough to force a perceptible linger to prevent this exact activity ;)

Comment: @penitent_tangent Were I to make user confirm something he didn't want to, I'd go through social engineering. I'd convince him he wants to. With this particular, I'd use words like *modern technologies*, *try what you can do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention geographic location. A competent javascript library e.g. [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home) or Google Analytics can be used to pinpoint to geographical location of users.

Comment: That's awesome. I can do this with the IP lookup library I'm using for carrier detection - obviously on the day everyone will be in the lecture hall, so I'll tell them to try the location bit when they get home.

Comment: Does't that require user confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

From the phishing point of view, which I consider most important, there are several dangerous things:

### Phishing

- Without add-ons, browsers will not usually warn you if there's one letter different in the address you're visiting. Even though URL scheme forbids zero-width characters and other Unicode nastiness, you still can oversee `l` (lowercase L), `1` (one), `I` (upper case I). There are also many unicode characters that look like normal alphabet. Maybe there's some blacklist on unicode characters like greek letters. Check [this site to play around](http://%E3%AF%99%E3%AF%9C%E3%AF%99%E3%AF%9F.net/). You can try to create some domain name like stackoverflow.com with greek `ο`.
- [JavaScript can alter URL **after** domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340186/607407). But I haven't seen hosting that would give users folder names in years. Still, it's creepy to see URL change without reload:

  ```
  window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
  ```
- Not sure if this applies, but last years HackADay.com revealed a hack where you can change `<a>` href after mouse button was pressed on link, effectively changing the target URL. But then again, you can also redirect browser using javascript...

### Personal data

- For this, the first thing I'd do is to check [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and `Document` on MDN. This is definitely gonna reveal some cool stuff that leaves battery power info just puny attempt to be scary:

  - **Window:**

    - [Window.ondevicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondevicemotion) - does what it suggests. assume you can also `Window.addEventListener("devicemotion", ...)`
    - [`Window.ondevicelight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondevicelight) - this one is very creepy but Firefox only
    - [Window.ondeviceorientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) - much more **widely supported** event for **device movement**. Wanna approximate the path your user walks and draw it on canvas? Or make an application that screams "*Put the fu*king phone down.*" until they put it on the table?
    - Also, there's like million methods to get various **screen properties**. Some of those were exploited to guess OS version, as different OS's have different menu bars taking different screen portion.
  - **Document:**

    - `document.referrer` - Wanna track your users?
    - You can detect presence of **ad-blocking addons** by creating elements like:

      ```
      <div id="advertisment" 
        class="ad advertisment ads banner"
        style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute; opacity: 0;">NOTHING
      </div>
      ```

      Then fetch `.getBoundingClientRect()` and assert non-zero dimensions.
  - You can **detect when document is being inspected by firebug**. (or you could in past, when firebug actually added elements in DOM to highlight nodes). These elements are invisible in Firebug but fire DOM mutation events.
- If user confirms, **[sound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and [video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) can be recorded**.
- I once created a script that was able to stream all **DOM mutations** on server allowing me to watch other user using web-site real-time. But I didn't finish it to production state unfortunately. But this is how I found about the firebug issue.
- There are other tricks to check if debug tools are running. These are usually various hacks, try to google something.
- Ever wondered if your users have **CORS enabled** localhost HTTP server running? I mean, isn't it worth a try?
- [`WebWorkers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) allow you to spawn threads on client machine. You could use this for **distributed processing** or just to **burn their battery**. As it doesn't affect GUI thread directly, they won't notice until it's too late. Also this sounds like a great way to generate hask cracks and crack certificates.
- You can **alter copied text**, possibly adding cross-site script hacks into it. Good trick is to offset your script with a shitload of spaces, so that it's not seen in typical text editor without text-wrap.
- Using [Desktop notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification), you can pretend you're an antivirus, windows update...

Comment: This is very exhaustive, thanks! I particularly like the idea of detecting ad blockers and burning battery has some interesting ransomware implications. Device movement is also really cool and there are so many other options on that page... if I do this again next year I think there's going to be a heap more scary stuff.

Answer (score -1):

What about any of these...

- You can profile their interests base off search history.
- Frequency they visit and from what locations.
- Build a profile of what time in the day they visit.
- Time spent on site
- What pages they spend most amount of time on.
- Profile based of hot area's on page clicks or where mouse curer is.
- You can profile typical user behaviour.

The result of all of this is 
 - Pushing data personalized marketing i.e what your seeing, is targeted to
   you, as an individual (google does this a lot with their ad's)

Comment: All great points, but I'm after information that can be surfaced on your first visit to a page by any bad actor - so no prior search history. Also mobile only, although I guess you could infer left handed / right handed-ness to a reasonable degree of accuracy if I had some buttons with sliced tap targets? But again, might not be well suited to a quick demo.

Comment: And sorry, the -1 isn't me - hopefully you can see that somewhere? I really appreciate the answer :)

Comment: But there's one -1 for me. The things you describe above are mostly only possible under special occasions (specifically only if you control google servers, or other user's favorite search engine). Other are rather broad to be described based on algorithm - it's like saying you can tell whether they are right/left handed based on mouse events. Statistically, you sure can, but as much as you can detect rose on a bitmap.

Comment: @penitent_tangent yeah sorry the "care to comment" was not directed at you, instead it was meant for the person who -1, as to me it does not make sense... and if it does... it would be helpful to know why. PS i never thought of "infer left handed / right handed-ness" even tho i suggested watching hot spots. +1 to you for that.