# Display Proper URL in Address Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery/Ajax to load html pages into a `div` on my website. I get links certain class to open up in the specified `div`. When doing this the address bar remains www.example.com. Due to the fact that I do have several pages that I will like to be able to share; so when people visit the links it will take them to the website but with the specific page loaded into the `div` container.

Here's a few lines of my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "pages/promo.html",
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#contentarea').html (content);
    }
    });
});



$('.menu_nav') .click (function () {
    var href = $(this) .attr('href');
    $('#contentarea').hide() .load(href).slideDown( 'very slow' )
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `var href = $(this) .attr('href');` is there supposed to be a space in between?

Comment: Are you trying to load new `url` page on `div` on your page and update the link to new `url` on same page?

Comment: @aug jQuery will ignore the whitespace, although it's conventional to not include.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the other pages are on your domain, you cannot do this. If the other pages are, see this StackOverflow question: [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page?rq=1).

Here's the deal: since you are loading a new page and you want the URL of the browser to point to that page, you should just give users a link. They know how to use the back button. (You could use the information in the linked answer to to change the URL to something like this: http://www.trillumonopoly.com/other-website.com.)

Comment: yess All the pages are on my server So It should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) object.

```js
$('#contentarea').html(content);
history.pushState({url: "pages/promo.html"}, "", "pages/promo.html");
```

With the use of the state `{url: "pages/promo.html"}` you can load your page into your `div` when your users navigate back/forward.

```js
$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.state != null)
    {
        // AJAX load e.originalEvent.state.url
    }
})
```

Comment: where do I put this on every page or the main page that the other pages are being loaded into? Or Do I just replace the top part of my script that I posted with this