# jQuery append tags to a URL without refreshing

Tags: jquery, html, fragment-identifier

I'm trying to create a "builder" page where the user can select an element from a drop down list and a builds a webpage of sorts.  We don't have access to a database for this information, so I'd like to be able to save the elements in the URL so the URL can be emailed or saved in a spreadsheet and the script will "write" the page every time someone accesses it (This is for mockup and delivery purposes only - not for production).

I tried using a hash (#), but when I do this, it gives me an error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #h=3&f=2`

I'm using equals signs to determine which variant of an object I'm looking for, which is why this is creating a problem.

When I switched to using `window.location.search` and using the question mark (?) in the address bar, it was working fine, but I don't know how to change the URL (with jquery/javascript) without refreshing the page this way.

I'd like the url to be something like `www.sample.com/?h=1&f=2` or `www.sample.com/#h=1&f=2`. Then, during the "building" process, I'd like to be able to append all of the different elements and their variants to the URL doing something like `window.location.hash = window.location.hash + "a=1";` or `window.location.hash = window.location.search + "a=1";`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Comment: I've been looking into that, trying to figure out how to get that url and keep appending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way should work.

```
var defaultState = {
   current: window.location.pathname
};

var requestParameters = [
   '?id=0',
   '&id=1',
   '&id=2' 
];

var path = window.location.pathname + requestParameters.join("");
window.history.pushState(defaultState, 'Title', path);
```

Result: http://example.com/?id=0&id=1&id=2

Comment: Ahh, so you are pushing the ids into an array and joining them to form a string.  I will try this out.  Thank you

Comment: Works beautifully!  I've changed it a bit by pushing the `?` into the array first, then instead of adding the `&` to the id in the array, I joined them with the `&` using `.join("&");` which puts the amp between any IDs

Comment: Glad it was what you were looking for, have a nice day.