# Change querystring without reloading/refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I want to change my url on click without refreshing page. For example my URL is `http://test.com?search=test`

When I click any filter value on the search page like "category" then my URL should be:

```
http://test.com?search=test$category=cat1
```

When I click on another category it should be:

```
http://test.com?search=test&category=cat1,cat2
```

When I click a brand then the URL should be:

```
http://test.com?search=test$category=cat1,cat2&brand=br1
```

When I deselect a category then the URL should be:

```
http://test.com?search=test$category=cat2&brand=br1
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using ui-router ?

Comment: No i am not using ui-router

Comment: I have the same problem. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).

Answer (score 1):

You can change it via the history api

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

In this case the relative /new-url will be set with the new title. You can experiment with it in the console. If you input this on stackoverflow.com the url will magically change to https://stackoverflow.com/new-url

Comment: This is not true. You can: HTML5 History API.

Comment: @Vohuman absolutely right!

Comment: I think in angular, for activating the HIstory API one should use the `$locationProvider` service and it's `.html5Mode(true)` method.