# Is it possible to avoid the white "flash" when clicking into another page in Wordpress? Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I come from the background of web app development but I'm new to CMS development.

In a web app, pages can be loaded as part of elements in the existing frame.

Can you avoid similarly reloading the whole page including the menu in Wordpress when you switch around pages?

Comment: Get the content of the other page using AJAX and use [change the URL to the new page's URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175285/single-page-site-pushstate

Comment: See also: https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/pushstate