# Is there any function available to modify the content occuring after "?" in django?

Tags: python, django, middleware

I am creating a middleware at my server end to modify the API calls in the following manner

```
http://example.com/xyz?jdvnjvjnfjAA536sddjjfjfjdjbdfjdh656dnjd5ndjvb
```

should be converted by the middleware to:

```
http://example.com/xyz?user=Tango&testID=123
```

where the earlier URL contains the encrypted string of the `user=Tango&testID=123`.

Hence simply put, the middleware decrypts the value and replaces it with the real string because i do not want to do decryption for over 50 API call view functions.

Is there any function available to modify the content occuring after "?"  in django ?

Comment: Why don't you use HTTPS? Note that if the problem is to obtain a certificate be aware that you can obtain free valid certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).  By the way: when providing example urls that aren't meant to be clickable you should always use `example.com` which is hosted by IANA to be a *safe* target. Using anything else may take users to websites full of malware or phishing websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the query-string from the server side.  You basically have 2 options:

1. issue a redirect response to tell the browser to request a different URL.  See the Django docs on [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).
2. embed the new URL in your response along with javascript to
   rewrite the location using the HTML5 History API, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page).