# Rails 4 remote true form request (for an ajax loader) with browser url updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails form that fires ajax by remote true as follows.

```
= form_tag(root_path, method: "get", remote: true) do ...
```

Works fine and all but how can I achieve the browser url to be updated with the search params ? 
What I want to achieve is that after successful response, the browser should be updated with the correct url as in normal rails html request.

Eg. localhost:3000/my_controller?status=canceled&search=mysearchkey&commit=Search

Answer (score 0):

In success response write this little js code

`window.history.pushState("", "", '/my_controller?&status=canceledsearch=mysearchkey&commit=Search');`

[Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

I hope it will help you out