# angularjs/JS Update url querystring without refresh/load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want update the url without page reloading or refresh. I've tried with below logic but no luck. Every time page is loading. Any help please?

```
  var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?k=' + vm.name + '&l=' + vm.sid;
            //var newurl = $location.protocol() + "//" + $location.host() + $location.path() + '?k=' + vm.name + '&l=' + vm.sid
            //window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
            //window.history.replaceState(null, null, newurl);
            //window.location.hash = 'k=' + vm.name + '&l=' + vm.sid
            //document.location = newurl;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Are you just trying to re-write the URL without loading? Or going to a new page?

Comment: Hi Mike, they are suggesting window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url"); but I'm already using window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl); Page is refresting if I'm using this logic.

Comment: Hi William, I'm rewriting the URL in same page.