# Add (get) params to url without page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With my code below I push every selected element to a array. I can push it to a url param with javascript like `window.location.href`. Can I add params to url without page reloading/redirect?

```
var keys = [];
keys.push({selected_element:object.key});
```

Needed structure is: `/index.php?element[]=546454&element[]=156151&element[]=343141`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use history.pushState...:

```
if (history.pushState) 
{
    var newQueryString = window.location.protocol + "//" + 
    window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 
    '?newStuff[]=123&whatever=909';

    window.history.pushState({path:newQueryString},'',newQueryString);
}
```

Comment: @user2956944 Glad to help - do tick as an accepted answer if it answers your question - cheers