# page doesn't update, till I scroll

Tags: jquery

I am using a scroll function, and recently added a refresh with it

> (cause I had a mail form and this was the easiest way to get the `?resp=0/` thing away. Yes I know there were other ways but this one was the best one to use for me, so please don't suggest other ways to do that process)

somehow sometimes when I refresh the page, it doesn't notice on what position it is. I have things starting on `display:none` but when it is on a certain place on the page it is `display:block`. When I scroll the page suddenly updates (like images appearing cause they get `display:block`, and the url changing from `index.php#this` to `index.php#that`). I would like it if it changed instantly on refresh so it doesn't need the scrolling first.

Most of the times it works fine but just sometimes it will act like that, I don't know were the problem is.

---

**code below:**

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 3) {
            $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
            if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
                window.location.replace("index.php#this");
            }
        }

        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 1.3) {
            $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
            if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
                window.location.replace("index.php#that");
            }
        }

        else if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3) {
            $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
            if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
                window.location.replace("index.php#things");
            }
        }
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3){
            $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
            if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
                window.location.replace("index.php#something");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider doing :

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#this");
        }
    }

    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 1.3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#that");
        }
    }

    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#things");
        }
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3){
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#something");
        }
    }
}).scroll()
```

Adding the `.scroll()` will call the event

---

Or you can put the event in a function and call it :

```
function onScroll () {
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#this");
        }
    }

    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() / 4.65) * 1.3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#that");
        }
    }

    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3) {
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#things");
        }
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height() / 4.65 * 0.3){
        $('.Attribute').removeClass('that').addClass('this'); (etc..)
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            window.location.replace("index.php#something");
        }
    }
}

$(window).bind('scroll', onScroll);
onScroll();
```

PS : is that normal that the first `if` is an else if ?

Comment: I just edited the first if statement, it has like 9 if's in my normal code so i chanced that part :) and i will try your code

Comment: Thanks it worked, I did the first one. (is one of them better then the other one? like one of them giving less problems?) also can't accept the answer yet, need to wait 5 minuts cause you was to fast :)

Comment: Well I don't know I often use the first one because it is less code (and looks clear to me), but the second one is nice too and the one from @Sandwell can also work

Comment: I got a code `<?php if (isset($_GET['resp']) ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $("#myBtn").click(); </script>';
}
?>`, first the url is still something with `!resp=..` so it will click the button fast. After like half a second it chanced to the good url. You know some way to avoid this? > Like the url changing before it refreshes

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do but if you just wanna change the url, you might find this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page] useful

Comment: I will just make another question for it but thanks for the fast replies :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$(window).on("load scroll",function(e) {
```