# javascript stop reloading page using location.replace ON IE9

Tags: javascript, replace, location, reload

I am using location.replace to change the URL on my application, I don't want to reload the page. Location.replace is NOT executed as an event driven.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: forgot to mention that this should work in IE9. Does these work on IE9

Comment: @user1015388 Probably not for IE9.  There is no way to do this in IE9.  But IE9 can't do most things.  I would suggest telling anyone that is using IE9 to upgrade immediately.