# Change URL parameter after page redirect

Tags: javascript

After redirect using javascript i am landing on the URL

```
window.location='https://ctsdemo1-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/0016F00001sM95VQAS?nooverride=1';
```

so redirection is successfull after redirection I want to remove "?nooverride=1" from the redirected page without refresh .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: You can use `history.replaceState` and regex. Don't have time to give a complete answer, but that's a good starting place.

Comment: The solution mention here is working before redirection its changing the current url but after redirection its not able to change the URL parameters