# Using the angular's location class correctly

Tags: angular

I'm on `http://myexaple.com/subFolder1`

and I want `this.location.go` to change the URL at the top from `http://myexaple.com/subFolder1` to `http://myexaple.com/subFolder2`

It's as simple as that.

So, I go

this.location.go('/subFolder2'); // what else would you do, anyway?!

But the result is
http://myexaple.com/subFolder1/subFolder2

The docs at https://angular.io/api/common/Location feel like what I'm doing seems to be the right thing to do.

What am I missing here?

Comment: its because `location` normalizes everything to the current path you're on. Try using the `Router` instead: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Comment: But router is an overkill for me. there must be another way to make a change on the URL ( without really requiring a new navigation process to start rolling as in the case with router. ) In the docs, it talks about "prepareExternalUrl", that might be a way out here, maybe. I'm not sure. But I could not try it out. How do you use prepareExternalUrl in the code?
 Do you do `this.location.go.prepareExternalUrl('/subFolder2')`?

Comment: with a little digging I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page. Essentially, you can just use javascript, like this: `window.history.pushState('data', "title", "/subFolder2");`

Comment: *"but router is overkill for me"* .. find that hard to believe

Comment: well, yes, out of context, it does sound weird but hey it is what it is in this particular app and in that particular instance.

Comment: QuietOran, your solution totally works. But I cannot seem to figure out what the 1st param is all about, Mozilla docs say it is the state obj but, I don't get it. state object —beginQuote--> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by pushState(). Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.The state object can be anything that can be serialized. <---endQuote. Ok, but what do I store in it? (Your "data" is still there BTW )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for redirecting from one route to another you should not be using `location.go`, it generally used to get `normalized url` on browser.

Rather you should use `Router` API's `navigate` method, which will take `['routeName']` as you do it while creating `href` using `[routerLink]` directive.

If you wanted redirect via URL only then you could use `navigateByUrl` which takes URL as string like `router.navigateByUrl(url)`

```
import { 
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, 
  RouteConfig, 
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  Location, //note: in newer angular2 versions Location has been moved from router to common package
  Router 
} from 'angular2/router';

constructor(location: Location, 
            public _userdetails: userdetails,
            public _router: Router){
    this.location = location;
}
login(){
    if (this.username && this.password){
        this._userdetails.username = this.username;
        //I assumed your `/home` route name is `Home`
        this._router.navigate(['Home']); //this will navigate to Home state.
        //below way is to navigate by URL
        //this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
    }
    else{
        console.log('Cannot be blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but in my use case, I must not navigate to that URL. I'm only updating the URL at the browser's address bar ( so it can be copied/shared etc. ) but I just do not want to navigate to that url.  ( Cause doing so, changes other things, which I do not need to get into).

Comment: Is the "navigate" just for the browser address bar update? It does not trigger the effect of really navigating to that URL, right? If so, this maybe the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what version of `Angular` are you using? It looks like it's Alpha or Beta..

Comment: I'm using angular 4.3 developer033.