# how to change url parameter value in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

i have a url in browser which has few parameter values.what i am trying to do is i want to change that parameter value to true and append back to url bar.

for example i have the `url:http://localhost:8080/movie/genre?genereId=61491607&saved=false` and i have save button, when i click on the save button, i should change the current url parameter `&saved=false` to `&saved=true`

how to do it?

here is what i have tried

```
url:http://localhost:8080/movie/genre?genereId=61491607&saved=false

<button class="save">save</button>

$('.save').click(function(){
    var defaultURL = window.location.href;
    //taking current url and changing the parameter value 
    location.hash = "saved=abc";
});
```

Comment: Please search your title before asking

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page