# How to add value in the URL when button click without reloading/relocating the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In this case, i just want to concat the value of `id` in the end of my url.

Anyway I just found out the solution.

I want to add value in the url.

My current URL is

```
localhost:1000//settings/tab=contact-types
```

Lets say i have this function

```
function view(id){ #lets say the value of id is 1
    localhost:1000//settings/tab=contact-types/1  #i want the current url look like this   
}
```

I have button in every row of my table and when I clicked it will run the `view()` function and show modal for viewing.

I want to add the specific value of my parameter in the url without reloading/relocating the page.

## thankyou!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by simply using this code on my function.

```
view: function(id)
{
    var newurl = window.location.href +"/"+id
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

the `window.location.href` define my current url

I just concat the value of `id` in the end of my current url and uses the

```
window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
```

to push it in the url.

## thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you need is pushState():

```
window.history.pushState("state obj or string", "your title", id);
```

Put the line above in your `view` function. For more info check: [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: if you are using the vue.js and vue-router, then this solution is not good so. because you can use the vue -router utilities regarding update URL.

Answer (score 1):

Please test this code

```js
export default {
    mounted(){
        this.updateURLQuery("tab", "reports")
    },
    methods: {
        updateURLQuery(query, value) {
      const componentLocation = window.location.pathname;
      this.$router.push({
       path: componentLocation,
       query: {
        [query]: value,
       },
      });
     },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do so by making use of the history api.

```
function view(id){ 
// lets say the value of id is 1
// localhost:1000//settings/tab=contact-types/1  #i want the current url look like this  
// get the current url
const oldUrl = location.href;
// get append the id to the url
const newUrl = oldUrl + '/' + id;
// update the url of the page
history.replaceState({}, '', newUrl);
}
```

Read More on History Push [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Thankyou, I also found out the answer btw we have the same logic. Thanks bro!

Comment: yeah. 

but there is a difference between push and replace. 

*pushState* would create a *new entry* in the navigation history while *replaceState* would replace the current *entity*.

Which seems to be what you wanted.
@MONSTER