# Update URL in browser while scrolling a page in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, hash, scroll, anchor, gatsby

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling page on a gatsby site. If the user clicks on a link in the menu, the website scrolls to a section with a matching id on the same page.
The scrolling itself works without any problem.
But I also want, that if the user just scrolls through the page - without clicking the links - the URL in the browser should update with hashes used in the section ids. e.g. website.com/#section1, website.com/#section2 etc.
None of the plugins I tried could do this so far:

- [gatsby-plugin-anchor-links](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/)
- [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)
- [react-update-url-on-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-update-url-on-scroll)

It seems to me that all of this plugin promise this feature, but it does not work for me.
Maybe Gatsby needs some extra configuration to make this work?

Comment: This is a JS/browser API called [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). As long as you're only changing the fragment, there isn't anything specific to React or Gatsby to consider.

Comment: Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39276694/203130

Comment: @coreyward , thank you for your answer, it did help me, but its not the answer that I was looking for. I can now update the URL in the browser, but I still can not detect the id of the div (of the section) that I am currently scrolling through. Actually I am looking for a solution with a react or gatsby plugin that can do that out of the box. If that does not exist, probably I could write a script for that, but I strongly prefer a working plugin.

Comment: Again, though, none of this is specific to Gatsby. Any React-based in-view library will do.

Comment: @coreyward can you please name one?

Comment: Technically this is out-of-scope for StackOverflow FYI. I use [this library](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer) a lot. It’s not going to do the work of modifying the fragment for you when something is in view, but the links I shared above should help you handle that part. If you get stuck, post a new question and share the code. :)