# How to change the web address,at the same time, only refresh a part of page?

Tags: javascript, web

I used Ajax to refresh page.but the address has not chenged.

```
function refresh(page) {
        let xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

I add this in order to [change address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

```
        let newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?foo=bar';
        window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
```

It's can work, but, I cant visit the website using this new url.
I want my web site like the [Android Guides](https://developer.android.com/guide). when I changed the address. only refresh a part of page.

For example:
My website is "mywebsite.com/test.php";
I add the newurl to change address like about,it become "mywebsite.com/php?foo=bar#". but when I input this address in address bar. the page still is "mywebsite.com/test.php"

Did you what I mean

Please excuse me for my bad english!

**solution:**
Maybe, I can ask this quesion like this,
'How to hot refresh the page?'

**reference**: [Vue.js](https://v3.vuejs.org/) and [javascript history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: Do you mean that the new section of the page is displayed, but that you cannot access that content at its URL? What is the new URL?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History