# Removing "?page" from paginated livewire view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

simple question: Can I "mute" a livewire pagination somehow so that there won't be any visible url-query changes like "?page=X"? I just want the app to paginate without showing the current page in the url. How can I do that?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need something to tell your application which data of the pagination it has to show. If you don't want something in the URL you have to make your own logic via POST Requests. I wouldn't recommend that, because it would lead to a very bad user experience. It is best to use the `?page=x` in the URL so the user knows whats going on.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options: either you have to use a custom pagination or you have to replace your URL with JavaScript.

[Replace URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)