# Flutter web - change the address bar URL without pushing a named route?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need the ability just to update the URL in the address bar, without pushing a named route. Is there maybe a plugin for it? It not, can I invoke JavaScript functions from the Flutter code?

Currently the one way I found to update the URL is the code below, which forces to "push" a new route, which I do not want to do. I just want to update the address bar.

***Note: I am using flutter web to create cross platform apps, so using dart:html is not an option as it fails the build on mobile.***

```
// Within the `FirstScreen` widget
onPressed: () {
  // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To update the URL without reloading the page in *JavaScript*, you can use the [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) API.

You can do the same for Flutter, using the [`window.history`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-html/History/pushState.html) available from `dart:html`:

- Note this only works for Flutter Web

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              html.window.history.pushState({}, '', '/test');
            },
            child: Text('Update the URL address bar'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- See: [Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3338642/12349734)

Comment: This gives an error when you try to build on mobile

Comment: @DavidSomekh Correct, well, your question title was for Flutter _Web_...

Comment: I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: @DavidSomekh it would appear that using the `universal_html` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) instead of `dart:html`. Haven't tested yet, but that's the purpose of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by creating two separate files; `web_url_strategy.dart` and `nonweb_url_stratagy.dart`

In the web_url_strategy.dart file I have a function like this:

```
updateUrl() {
  window.history.replaceState(null, 'title', '/test');
}
```

In the nonweb_url_strategy.dart file there is just an empty function with the same name.

Then I import it where I need to use it like:

```
import 'package:project/utils/nonweb_url_strategy.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'package:project/utils/web_url_strategy.dart';
```