# jQuery loads external HTML file but does not stay still after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to do something different without knowing if it is a good idea or not

I have a navigation menu as the following:

```
...
<li><a href = "#mhome">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "#mfaq">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href = "#mcontact">Contact</a></li>
...
```

I do not want to use a server-side scripting because it takes more time to make db connection and define some configuration, and not want to multiply the pages for each one. So I made a master page index.php

in `body` section

there are two elements:

an `h3` element to display the page title and a `div` to display the content which is called from another html source.

```
...

  <div class="container">

    <h3 id="pageTitle"></h3>

    <div id="pageContent"></div>

  </div>

...
```

I am using jQuery's click event to load the page into the div

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href^='#m']").click(
        function() {
            $("#pageTitle").text($(this).text());
            $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href").substring(1) + ".html"); //removing # char.
        });
```

});

It works fine. But when I press F5 it returns the initial state as normal. How can I load the current page by referencing the address bar (I can see eg. `sitename/#mfaq`)  when page is refreshed.

I think, first I need to detect if page is refreshing and load the corresponding html file in according to the `#m****` on the addressbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358928/whats-the-best-library-to-do-a-url-hash-history-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this. It works well. But I am not sure about performance issues:

```
$(function() {

    var address = $(location).attr('href');
    var hash = address.lastIndexOf("#");
    var page = address.substring(hash+1);


    if (hash < 1)
    {
        $("#pageContent").load("mhome.html");
        $("#pageTitle").html("Default Page Title");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pageContent").load(page + ".html");
        $("#pageTitle").html($("a[href='" + address.substring(hash) + "']").text());
    }

    $("a[href^='#m']").click(
            function() {                   
                $("#pageTitle").text($(this).text());
                $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href").substring(1) + ".html");
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   $("a[href^='#m']").click( function(evt) {
     // ------  This should work
     // renamed parameter elem to evt like corrected in comment
     evt.preventDefault();
     $("#pageTitle").text($(this).text());
     $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href").substring(1) + ".html");
   });
});
```

Comment: It works, but your choice of parameter name is odd. It's an **event**, not an element, so calling it `elem` makes no sense.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question, he specifies that when he presses "F5" the page refreshes and does not load the current html that was loaded by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your DOM ready function:

```
if (window.location.hash != "") {
    $("#pageTitle").text($("a[href='"+window.location.hash+"']").text());
    $("#pageContent").load(window.location.hash.slice(1) + ".html");
}
```