# Preserve content while loading new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page (see image for a description), where the user has to choose a few options. 
[image: page description]

The idea is, you first click on a link in the box on top. Then enter a string in the searchbox which will show you relevant links in div1. When you click on a link in div1, relevant links will be displayed in div2. Then, after clicking on a link in div2, you'll get your result in div3.

I use ajax/javascript to create the links for div1 and 2 and to get the result for div3.
The problem is, when I click on any link on my page, the searchbox will be cleared and contents in div1, div2 and the searchbox disappear even though the next step (e.g. displaying the next links) will be successfully executed.

What can I do to prevent this and preserve the contents of the searchbox, div1 and div2?

My current html-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
      <script src="inc/OnlineLogs.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>Logs</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="getOnlineIds()">
      <div class="main">
          <div class="navigation">
              <a href="?loc=bad">bad</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=erf">erf</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=ess">ess</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=ffb">ffb</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=goe">goe</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=hal">hal</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=ham">ham</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=jen">jen</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=koe">koe</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=lei">lei</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=mue">mue</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=rau">rau</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=wil">wil</a> • 
              <a href="?loc=wit">wit</a>
          </div>
          <div class="search">
              Suche: <input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="getOnlineComms()">
          </div>
          <div class="onlines" id="onlinelist"></div>
          <div class="ids" id="ids"></div>
          <div class="log" id="log"></div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X7aXG/1/

**EDIT:** I edited the problem description. Clicking any link will remove the contents of div1, div2 and the searchbox, even though the next step will be executed.

Comment: Please, please, provide relevant code in question of javascript methods used... A plus would be to provide a jsFiddle too

Comment: I tried to fiddle it a bit up. :)

Comment: The searchbox shouldn't be cleared if you're using ajax (unless you explicitly clear it in the code), are you sure the page isn't refreshing?

Comment: @markpsmith I don't know if it's called "refreshing" when I click on a link which simply adds a few parameters to the url like the links in the top box... They don't do anything else than that.

Comment: id="onlinelist" and id="ids" - are they div1 and div2?  in your fiddle I can see ids = msg; and idlist.innerHTML=""; on the ajax success callback - is this deleting the contents?

Comment: onlinelist = div1 and ids = div2, yes. In my fiddle, i reset the content of div1 before filling it. That's right. But I don't think that this is the problem. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links don't simply "add parameters to the URL", they change the query params which requires a server request which will refresh your entire page.

If you want to avoid refreshing the page but still want changes in the URL (to make it bookmarkeable) you can **store the location in the URL hash** (i.e. instead of `?foo=bar` use `#foo=bar`)

There exist many libraries ([see this discussion for some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358928/whats-the-best-library-to-do-a-url-hash-history-in-jquery)) that help with managing the hash state of your page and reacting to changes in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the script that AJAX gets you list for links1, check if

```
$('#input').val() != ""
```

Comment: That does not seem to help me with my problem. :/

Comment: I assumed that one of your mechanisms is triggering additional call to mechanism that retrieves first set of links for Div1, that would explain Div2 not being affected. Checking if it's not firing empty request and then getting empty response would have solved your problem.

Comment: Could you try using explorer and check if you get same behaviour. I am assuming that modifying url fires additional requests on chrome, that get empty response and clear the links.

Comment: It doesn't matter which link I click. The contents will always be removed.

Comment: Same behaviour in IE9.

Comment: Why are you skipping 1st element? for (index = 0; index < ids.length; ++index)

Comment: I am assuming a lot today, but could you try storing ids in global javascript array var ids = []; and see if not touching url affects things.

Comment: `++index` is not skipping the first element. The last part of an for-loop is touched, after the iteration.

Comment: I don't know how to use global arrays in java, yet. Have to try it.